# SnapKit Android - Getting IllegalArgumentException when calling send method

Tags: android, snapchat, snapkit, android-12

Calling the SnapCreativeKitApi.send method with Android compile sdk as 31 throws a IllegalArgumentException. Does Anyone know when we will we get a sdk update from snapchat. The latest sdk version(v1.13.0)[https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/changelog] does not have the fix.

Here is the exception im getting.

```
IllegalArgumentException: com.test.test: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) 
requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE 
or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at com.snapchat.kit.sdk.creative.api.SnapCreativeKitApi.sendWithCompletionHandler(SourceFile:151)
    at com.snapchat.kit.sdk.creative.api.SnapCreativeKitApi.send(SourceFile:100)
```

Comment: Why is this question closed its a legit issue

Comment: https://docs.snap.com/snap-kit/changelog/ The issue is fixed from v1.13.1